# How to disable IR emitter on Kinect2 using iai_kinect2 or libfreenect2?

Tags: kinect, ros, vision, openkinect

Is there a way to disable the infrared emitter of Kinect2 (i.e., KinectOne) using the library freenect2 or its ros binding iai_kinect2?

I need it to avoid interferences among Kinect2 and Primesense sensor.

In alternative, covering the emitter should do the trick, right? Or Do I risk to mess with the depth readings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to turn off the IR-emitter, while still using the Kinect2. Neither in the official Microsoft SDK, nor in libfreenect2.

But it wouldn't matter anyways, since you won't get any depth readings from the device without the IR-emitter on the Kinect2.

Comment: As far as I understand the OP, he wants to disable the kinect IR emitter to avoid that the light emitted by it disturbs the measurements of the primesense sensor (while maybe still using the RGB image of the kinect?). So in this case it would matter.

Comment: Sure, if he only needs the depth values from the Primesense sensor, he could cover the IR-emitters of the Kinect2. That won't interfere with the RGB image of the Kinect2.